# getIdentifier() or getChildAt()! Which of the two is more efficient to access button/view when loop's big and how?

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-button, android-viewgroup

**Scenario:**
My Activity contains a few buttons with ID: btn1, btn2 and so on. I want the code to access these buttons through loop counter. So, which of the below two approaches is more efficient? Thanks!

**getChildAt():**

```
for (int optionCounter = 0; optionCounter < bigNumber; optionCounter++) {   
        optionButton = (Button) buttonRelativeLayout.getChildAt(optionCounter); //Layout contains Buttons
        optionButton.setText("some text");   }
```

NOTE: buttonRelativeLayout was just introduced artificially to access Buttons by child number. Which otherwise doesn't serve any purpose.

**getIdentifier():**

```
 for (int optionCounter = 0; optionCounter < bigNumber; optionCounter++) {
   String buttonID = "btn" + optionCounter;
   int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", "com.sample.project");
   optionButton = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
   optionButton.setText("some text");   }
```

Note: use of getIdentifier function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name -[Developers Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). And the reference document stops there.

Thanks again!

Comment: You're aware that you can programmatically set an id on a view? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int) You also have this way to generate unique ids: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29

Comment: Thanks JohanShogun! But my question only concerns about accessing View in a loop using loop counter not setting ID or generating ID.

Comment: In that case getChildAt is more efficient, it's a single look up while your other code uses multiple look ups. To be sure, take a times tamp before and after each look, that way you can know which is the most efficient.

Comment: Thanks, JohanShogun!